# Mixed parametrization for the multivariate Gaussian using submatrices of the covariance and inverse covariance matrices

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, parameterization

I'm interested in specifying a zero-mean multivariate Gaussian distribution with a certain covariance structure over one subset of variables $A$, and a certain *inverse* covariance structure between the remaining variables $B$ and the variables in $A$. In particular, I want the distribution to have covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and inverse covariance $\Theta := \Sigma^{-1}$, such that $\Sigma_{A,A} = \Sigma_1$, $\Theta_{A,B} = \Theta_1$, and $\Theta_{B,B} = \Theta_2$. I've tried looking for mixed parametrization of the Gaussian distribution, but the only results that I've found use a mixture of the inverse covariance matrix and the mean; not different parts of the covariance matrix and its inverse.

Comment: Check out https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.00134. It goes in the same direction, specifying a model by zeros in the covariance and inverse covariance.